# Reading excel rows from Execute sql task SSIS

Tags: ssis, etl

Is it possible to read all rows from Excel sheet through Execute SQL Task from SSIS and reading each value in for loop container [image]?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably could and save the output to a variable, which you can use in the loop container. There may be a gotcha with permissions and/or linked server setup.

Here's another approach:

1. Create Data Flow
2. Create Data Connection to Excel file
3. Create Excel file source transformaion
4. Use Recordset Destination to populate a variable
5. Use the variable in your loop, setting Enumerator property to **Foreach ADO Enumerator**

[image]

Comment: i cannot able to pass the output from recordset destination to for loop container.